# Samsung s6 how do I find SSID

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-6

How do I find the SSID on my Samsung S6? I don't know what the Android version/variant is or how to find it. I recently updated the phone and the icons now have rounded iOS style borders

Update

I found the Android version is 7.0 under settings > about device > software info, and now know that the UX is the 'Samsung Experience'.

Comment: I don't see any connection between SSID and the behaviour described. However, suggested ways in answer

Comment: Oh, I'm describing the UX so someone may be able to tell me where to find my android version, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

- Your Android Version : Settings → About Phone → Android Version
- [SSID Notify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.playmoremusic.android.wifiname) can help you with SSID and other details of connection
- [Phone Info Samsung](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.playmoremusic.android.wifiname) is a versatile app which gives you a ton of info about your device

According to [this post](https://www.sammobile.com/2017/03/09/galaxy-s6-edge-running-android-7-0-nougat-pictures/) from a reputed site *rounded* icons are an OS feature in Android 7

Comment: No, there's no settings - about phone to determine the android version. +1 for the helpful post on rounded icons. I want to find the SSID via my settings

Comment: Samsung may be calling it slightly different like Settings - about device or something else but it has to be there. You can't find SSID from within settings

Comment: It's settings - about device - base band version. See [this](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00048781/)

Comment: No I don't see base band version there. I've updated the question with your help

Answer (score 0):

I found this guide which describes how it can be done by using a file manager with root file access:

http://www.theandroidsoul.com/view-wifi-password-android/